# Bootstrap 3 sign glyphicon with white circle background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Problem

Is there any way to make a Bootstrap 3.2 sign glyph to have a **white background**? It is being displayed on a coloured background. I've got an [example on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6srLJ3sJeF) but it has a white trim that is annoying.

### CSS

```
.glyph-white-background {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Remove class glyph-red

Comment: @KaushikThanki - thanks for the suggestion. I want to keep the red circle/sign but have the exclamation (or other) sign white if it is on a coloured background.

Comment: It's absurd that Bootstrap doesn't seem to offer a simple exclamation icon. Can't you use FontAwesome instead? `<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>`, then you can add the red circle yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I had a play with the bootply and there may well be better ways of doing this but for now I sorted it by placing an inner span inside the glyphicon element and positioning it so that its border does not overlap the parents.

```
<div class="header">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign glyph-background">
    <span class="inner"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The CSS positions the inner to provide the red background for the icon only.

```
.header {
    background-color:#3AA3CB;
    font-size: x-large;
}

.glyph-background {
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:2;
}

.inner {
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hJhgkL0R5g)

Answer (score 1):

I followed [@Duroth 's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070341/bootstrap-3-sign-glyphicon-with-white-circle-background#comment-50161215) advice and it works just fine.
**HTML**

```
<span class="not-available-icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> </span>
```

**CSS**

```
.not-available-icon {
    background-color: #9D5A5B;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/theAccountant/7re2c0jn/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any color in :

```
.glyph-white-background {
  background-color: red;//Say red
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

You should specify white color for class .glyph-red

```
.glyph-red {
  color: white;
}
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: And that reverses the issue with a now red aura surrounding the icon.

Comment: Removing ` background-color` property `.glyph-white-background` will give the icon original background color.

Comment: And that's not the desired outcome... all you've done is changed the background color to red and the color to white. Look at your own bootply, it has a red border around the outside.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bootply.com/IRTWifeP2u

I consider this absolute overkill for what you're trying to accomplish, but at least it seems to work.

Using a [gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), I generated an image with a radial gradient that drops from 100% to 0% opacity at around 67% / 68%, making the image fully transparent just before it hits the edge of the icon.

The following CSS *should* work for just about every circle icon:

```
 .glyph-white-background {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 67%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 68%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(67%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(68%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 67%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 68%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 67%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 68%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 67%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 68%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 67%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 68%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
```

Ofcourse, do mind your [cross-browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).